# LFTP - command that transfers and replaces a single file no matter if the files differ or not

Tags: ftp

I am looking for a command that always copies and replaces a specified file on a server no matter if the files differ or not.

So far I used this:

```
lftp -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no; open -u user,pass server;mirror --reverse --verbose --file=app.wsgi   --target-directory=~/target; bye"
```

However, this command only works if I have changed the app-wsgi file. I also added the `--delete-first` option without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unconditionally upload a file, use simple `put` command:

```
cd ~/target; put app.wsgi
```

See [LFTP manual](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html).